# Web Application - Database Logging

Tags: php, database, laravel, logging

I'm working on an application with about 75 Database tables.  Anytime a record is added / updated in a particular table, we want to Log this data in some other storage.

As of now, there's essentially a Log table for each table.  i.e table_a_log, tableB_log, etc.

Events are being fired when Models are saved (Laravel app) to log the data in the respective Log table.

My question is: is the best way to approach logging? If we're storing logs in the Database, should we used a separate Datatase for logging?   Are there better alternatives to logging?

Comment: Not sure if there is a hard and fast rule as such. What is your main concern?

Comment: Well this is more like User Analytics logging, so things like file logging wouldn't work because these would need to be searchable (maybe not from the app, but after the fact) so we can say "most users who Favorited X, did so between these dates during this promotion".  But with 75 tables (with a log table for each that could grow to millions of records per table) i was just curious how folks generally handle this

Comment: You would treat the analytics data like any other database resource, you will have to consider optimization when the database grows in size. I would suggest reading up some scalability resources, for eg: http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using 5.2, here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#logging) for logging inside of Laravel.  You can push info to the standard Laravel logs using something like `Log::info('UsersController@store was used');`

For more advanced logging, you can use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) which is included in Laravel right out of the box.

Edit: To give a more complete answer to your actual question, it depends on what you use the logged information for.  If you just want to keep track of what's going on to make sure nothing breaks, the regular Laravel logging works just fine.  I would personally avoid the way you currently have it (logs within a database) because that means each time you save or update something, you're doing two different sql actions (saving the actual data and then saving the log).  Plus, Laravel's logging and Monolog are there for a reason.